# Media Player not working in Android

Tags: android, audio, spinner

The idea is to click the spinner and have it give you a list of times to play the sound. once you pick a sound and click the button it should play. it doesnt work and I cant figure out why. I have a home screen and a home activity that when you click a button take you to a new activity and a new layout. I can get the new layout and new activity to load, which is the one featured below, but the sound and spinner do not start.

```
package com.androidsleepmachine.gamble;

package com.androidsleepmachine.gamble;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Ship extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
public static final int[] TIME_IN_MINUTES = { 30, 45, 60 };
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public Handler handler = new Handler();
public Button button1;
public Spinner spinner1;

// Initialize the activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.ship);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,   
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
}

// Play the sound and start the timer
private void playSound(int resourceId) {
    // Cleanup any previous sound files
    cleanup();
    // Create a new media player instance and start it
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceId);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    // Create the timer to stop the sound after x number of milliseconds
    int selectedTime = TIME_IN_MINUTES[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, selectedTime * 60 * 1000);
}

// Handle button callbacks
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSubmit:
            playSound(R.raw.ocean_ship);
            break;
    }
}

// Stop the sound and cleanup the media player
public void cleanup() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
    // Cancel any previously running tasks
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

// Runnable task used by the handler to stop the sound
public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        cleanup();
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in your `switch` statemenet. You are checking for the `id` of `button1` but the only button that you have assigned the `listener` to is `button1` which has an `id` of `btnSubmit`. So your `playSound()` function is never getting called.

Change your `onClick()` to

```
    // Handle button callbacks
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSubmit:
            playSound(R.raw.ocean_ship);
            break;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

For your `ArrayAdapter` try something like

```
ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TIME_IN_MINUTES);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);          
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I seem to have way overlooked the button name issue, thank you for the reply. I am testing it now. would that fix the spinner setting the time issue? I am using an emulator, however when I first built the app(full disclosure, I have been teaching myself for about a week now) I just had each button set to play a clip and the sounds would play in the emulator.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `Spinner` issue is...please describe. But I don't see you doing anything with the `Spinner` apart from initializing it

Comment: int selectedTime = TIME_IN_MINUTES[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, selectedTime * 60 * 1000);                 at least that is what I thought would call the spinner to put in those values so that I can get a time for the song to play.

Comment: Ok, I see that line now but what is/isn't happening? Have you set a breakpoint to see what results you are getting versus the expected results?

Comment: I am way way new at this so I am assuming I am missing something very easy. What I want to happen is on the ship.java class have the spinner load the values that you see in the line and then when selected will set the timer for the song to play for the selected time peried. When the ship.java loads the spinner is blank when clicked. Also the app fails when the button is clicked though the song will start to play

Comment: I see, you need to set the `Adapter` for the `Spinner` with those values. I will be away here soon for a bit but [look at this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) and see if you can figure that out. If not I will try to help when I return

Comment: spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
  spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(TIME_IN_MINUTES);            I added that but it doesnt help or build. I have not been able to find a good example for me to follow to build one of these either. I keep looking at tutorials but they are all over the place and not usually what I am looking for and I dont know enough to adapt what they are teaching.

Comment: Have you initialized `adapter` in some way?

Comment: @user2727048 see my edit on initializing the adapter. Make sure to do that before trying to call `setAdapter()` on your `Spinner`. If it doesn't work then please update with the error.

Comment: I dont think I know how to do that the right way, what I attempted to do is what I replied with earlier. I am sure I bit off more then I could chew with this being my first try at android. however, I learn programming by following examples and then recreating.

Comment: I put an example on there of initializing the `adapter`. Did you try again?

Comment: My appologies, I didnt see uptop where you added that. I just put it in, my only question is what to put in the R.layout.simple_spinner_item. Should that be the layout that contains the spinner1? (in this case its the ship.xml layout) Also what would the correct variable, based on what I have already, be used in place of the <integer>?

Comment: [See the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, java.util.List<T>)) it is a `TextView` for the `Spinner` `Views`. `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` is a built-in Android resource. You should probably use that for now but you can create your own to use for more customization

Comment: I re-edited my code with what i thought you were telling me to do. The spinner still doesnt load or do anything when pressed, and the app force closes when the button is pressed.

Comment: See the new update in my answer. You haven't set the `Adapter` on the `Spinner`. As far as the crash, I can't say without knowing the error but make sure your `Button` is the correct `id` as in your xml.

Comment: And change your `Array` from `int` to `Integer`

Comment: ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, TIME_IN_MINUTES , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item) that line generates an error telling me to change the argument to match ArrayAdapter<Integer> (Context, int). Or to change TIME_IN_MINUTES back to int. if I do that then the bracket with the numbers following the TIME_IN_MINUTES errors telling me to change it back to Integer

Comment: Yes, sorry, I changed it. The list should come last in the constructor.

Comment: CodeMagic You are a Gentlemen and a scholar. It is working just like I wanted it to. The force close must have been related to the spinner because it no longer force closes either. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate you taking time out of your day to help a uber beginner. One last question, if it is possable is there any way to pre load anything into the array? it shows up empty until it is clicked, is it possable for it to say something like "select your time" or something like that before they click it?

Comment: @user2727048 You are most welcome. You can thank me by accepting the answer as correct by clicking the check mark next to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this on emulator? Mediaplayer doesnt work on emulator. You will have to test this in real device.

Comment: The song will play not when the button is clicked but the app then force closes.

Comment: _"Mediaplayer doesnt work on emulator."_ Huh? Since when? Audio playback in the emulator has certainly worked in the past.

Comment: The mediaplayer is working in the emulator for me, I just am not getting a force close when the button is clicked and the sound starts as well as the spinner not working